# Meaning of (s) in a word

Tags: grammar, american-english

I have seen the use of (s)  inside the two brackets. For instance

> Others in a way.
>
> Also Other(s) in another way.

What does the word including (s) in brackets define? Does other(s) = other or others ?

Comment: '_(s)_' indicates that there is a possibility of a plural existence. In other words, '_other(s)_' means there is a possibility of more than one person, so the word should take a plural form, if such a situation occurs.

Comment: @VarunKN Thank you for your quick response. Can we use it in a sentence as " if you have any other(s) thing ,please submit another... " ?

Comment: To provide an answer for a question like that, you might have to include more context. You can edit the same question as a part of this answer and people will help you out. But please make sure you include more context, because the sentence you provided has insufficient context or content.

Comment: (s) is hard to pronounce and is usually a product of lazy or incompetent writing.  It should be avoided. It often appears on forms or in computer-generated captions.  Even in those places some readers dislike it.  In most kinds of text it shouldn't appear.  You shouldn't say "Have you any other(s)?" - just say "Have you any others?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plural in brackets is used mostly in cases when the singular form is more common while the plural form may rarely occur. Notice that the brackets usually stand after the appropriate word.

- If you have any other question(s), please ask.
- Do you have any other job(s)?